# Java LinkedList Iterators: Why are they returning only Objects?

Tags: java, iterator, linked-list, type-conversion

Here, I'll just post my code:

```
    int len = InternalList.size();

    ListIterator<E> forward = InternalList.listIterator( 0 );
    ListIterator<E> backward = InternalList.listIterator( len );
    while( forward.hasNext() && backward.hasPrevious() )
    {
        E next = forward.next();
        E prev = backward.previous();

        // When the object references are the same, we expect to be at the
        // center of the list (for odd-numbered lists?); we're done
        if( next == prev )
            return true;

        // Otherwise, if the object values aren't the same, we're not a
        // palindrome
        if( !((E)next).equals( prev ) )
            return false;
    }
```

And here's the internal list:

```
private LinkedList<E> InternalList;
```

So basically my problem is the last if statement only checks Object's equals() method; not the E's equals().  If forcibly casting it doesn't work, what does?

Comment: And yes, I know I could optimize this for even-numbered lists. :P

Comment: It's not an optimization, it's a fix, unless visiting the elements twice is harmless...

Comment: Unless we're talking about huge lists or performance necessity, I mean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct implementation of `equals(Object)` will be chosen at runtime, due to runtime polymorphism. Why do you think that's not the case?

Actually, you might have made a common mistake and implemented `equals(ASpecificType)` instead of `equals(Object)`: you want to override the `equals(Object)` method from `java.lang.Object`. Specifying a different parameter type means you no longer override that method.

A common `equals()` implementation for `ASpecificType` could start like this:

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {
  if (this==o) {
    return true;
  } else if (o==null || o.getClass() != getClass()) {
    return false;
  }
  ASpecificType other = (ASpecificType) other;
  // insert specific comparison here
  return result;
}
```

Comment: +1 for posting the `equals` skeleton, since I agree this is the most likely cause of the problem (and hence the type-checking and casting will not be present).

Comment: Yes it appears that was the mistake I made.

Comment: @Hamster: the reason you need to cast manually is that `equals()` is specified to allow comparison with arbitrary objects. Most of those comparison will of course return `false´, but they must be supported anyway.

Answer (score 5):

The runtime types of the elements returned from the iterators are not (and indeed cannot be) changed.  They're assigned to fields of type `E`, which may well be erased to `Object` at runtime (depending on the generic bounds) but this won't affect the objects themselves.

When `equals()` is invoked, it's a non-static method and so is invoked on whatever the class of the `next` object happens to be.  If this class doesn't have an overridden equals method then sure, the default `Object.equals` will be used.  However, if this object's class directly or indirectly overrides equals, the most specific override will be used.

In other words, this code should be fine (and the cast is completely unnecessary).

I suggest that you double-check you've overridden `equals` correctly in the class in question.  I would guess that you've implemented it as something like:

```
public class MyFoo {
    ...
    public boolean equals(MyFoo other) {
       ...
    }
}
```

whereas the argument must be of type **Object**, otherwise you're just overloading the equals method instead of overriding it.  If you're using Java 6, you can add the `@Override` annotation to your method, which will catch this sort of error.

Comment: It does have one.  But the debugger steps show me this still goes through Object's equals() method.  That is all I know so far.

Answer (score 1):

1. The casting casts `E` to `E` so it doesn't do anything.
2. `equals` should work without casting.
3. As you posted in the comment, `next == prev` will not work for even-numbered lists.

Concerning how to implement `equals`:

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {
  if(this == o) { return true; }
  if(o == null) { return false; }
  if(o instanceof [ClassOfThis]) {
    o = (Type)o;
    // compare here.
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: `instanceof getClass()` will not compile. `instanceof` expects a class name and not an expression returning a `Class` object. You'll need to use `isInstance()`.

Comment: Agreed, thanks. Actually, I never write it in such a way. I use the class I have. Updated.